# Can multiple clients connect to a Laravel dev server simultaneously?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel app running locally using `./vendor/bin/sail up`. I also have a trivial NodeJS server (running locally as well) that waits 60 seconds on each request and returns dummy data. The Laravel app makes a request to the Node app and becomes unresponsive to client requests until the 60 seconds are up.

Is this a limitation of the Laravel dev server? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Laravel uses `php artisan serve` underneath sail, which in turn uses the [built-in server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), which by default "runs only one single-threaded process."

However, "You can configure the built-in webserver to fork multiple workers in order to test code that requires multiple concurrent requests to the built-in webserver. Set the PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS environment variable to the number of desired workers before starting the server. This is not supported on Windows."

Adding `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=5` to my `.env` file fixed the issue.

Comment: "This is not supported on Windows." - is there any way to make it work?